# How to close fileshare sessions programmatically

Tags: windows

I need to programmatically close opened file share sessions on windows server 2008. Does winapi offer some such functionality?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [NetSessionDel function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525381(v=vs.85).aspx) allows you to close one or more sessions from the server.  You can specify the client computer name, username, or both.